# Laravel MySQL groupby created_at with date format without time

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a table column named `created_at` type `datetime`.
and I want to use `groupby` for `created_at` with **date only and without time**.
Here's my existing code :

```
$data = BloodPressureHistory::where('user_id', $id)
    ->groupBy('created_at')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(7);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupBy(DB::raw())` and `DATE_FORMAT` like this:

```php
$data = BloodPressureHistory::where('user_id', $id)
                           ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%Y-%m-%d")'))
                           ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                           ->paginate(7);
```

Comment: Thanks @TsaiKoga, But I got syntax error "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055"

Comment: I just added some codes thats why I got an error. Sorry for that, but thanks for your answer. It works :) @TsaiKoga

Answer (score 0):

```
  $data = BloodPressureHistory::where('user_id', $id)
        ->groupBy(function ($item){
            return \Illuminate\Support\Carbon::parse($item->created_at)->format('Y-m-d');
        })
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->paginate(7);
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohammed Aktaa, But I got an error "stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given"